# Is is possible to use Vapor 3 Postgres Fluent in a standalone script?

Tags: swift, vapor

I am experimenting with a standalone script that will query a Postgres database using Vapor and Fluent. In a normal Vapor API application this is simply done by:

```
router.get("products") { request in
    return Product.query(on: request).all()
}
```

However, in a standalone script, since there is no "request", I get stuck on what to replace the "request" or `DatabaseConnectable` with. Here's where I get stuck on:

```
import Fluent
import FluentPostgreSQL

let databaseConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost",
                                              username: "test",
                                              database: "test",
                                              password: nil)

let database = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: databaseConfig)

let foo = Product.query(on: <??WhatDoIPutHere??>)
```

I tried creating an object that conforms to `DatabaseConnectable`, but couldn't figure out how to correctly get that object to conform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an event loop group to be able to make database requests. SwiftNIO's `MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup` is good for this:

```
let worker = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 2)
```

You can change the number of threads used as you need.

Now you can create a connection to the database with that worker:

```
let conn = try database.newConnection(on: worker)
```

The connection is in a future, so you can `map` it and pass the connection in your query:

```
conn.flatMap { connection in
    return Product.query(on: connection)...
}
```

Make sure you shutdown your worker when you are done with it using [`shutdownGracefully(queue:_:)`](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Classes/MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup.html#/s:3NIO27MultiThreadedEventLoopGroupC18shutdownGracefullyy8Dispatch0I5QueueC5queue_ys5Error_pSgctF)

Comment: What exactly does the closure return and how do I get to it? It it like any other async method via a typealias and a completion handler? Does not seem to work?

Comment: @user1700737 In this case the closure would probably return `EventLoopFuture<[Product]>`, but really any type could be contained in the future. You can get the value from the future using the `.map` and `.flatMap` methods. I suggest you read Vapor's documentation on [Async](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/async/overview/).

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. I now got the query to work and can get data out of the base. But If I want to save an object it still needs a DatabaseConnectable?

Comment: Ahh that worked now also. I got it. 10000000 thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Hello everyone! @CalebKleveter can you or someone else please update your answer to Vapor 4? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62560531/vapor-4-postgresql-crud-without-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

The above is very good, but just clarify how simple it is, when you get it, I have made a small test example for this. Hope it helps you.

```
final class StandAloneTest : XCTestCase{
    var expectation : XCTestExpectation?
    func testDbConnection() -> Void {
        expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Wating")
        let databaseConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "your.hostname.here",
                                                      username: "username",
                                                      database: "databasename",
                                                      password: "topsecretpassword")
        let database = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: databaseConfig)
        let worker = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 2)
        let conn = database.newConnection(on: worker)

        let sc = SomeClass( a:1, b:2, c:3  ) //etc

        //get all the tupples for this Class type in the base
        let futureTest = conn.flatMap { connection in
              return SomeClass.query(on: connection).all()
        }
        //or save a new tupple by uncommenting the below
        //let futureTest = conn.flatMap { connection in
        //    return someClassInstantiated.save(on: connection)
        //}

        //lets just wait for the future to test it 
        //(PS: this blocks the thread and should not be used in production)
        do{
            let test = try futureTest.wait()
            expectation?.fulfill()
            worker.syncShutdownGracefully()
            print( test )
        }catch{
            expectation?.fulfill()
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

//Declare the class you want to test here using the Fluent stuff in some extension
```