# Vapor 3 PostgreSQL CRUD without requests http

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am creating backend based on Vapor 3.1.10 using Xcode 11.2 and Swift 5.1, database is PostgreSQL 12. I have a question: how to interact with database (CRUD) without POST and GET requests. All tutorials show how to CRUD only based on Request through HTTPS. But what if my app needs to save something in database without interacting with network? Look at my code:

```swift
import Vapor
import FluentPostgreSQL

final class Device: PostgreSQLModel {        
    var id: Int?
    var isWorking: Bool
    var serial: Int

    init(isWorking: Bool, serial: Int) {
        self.isWorking = isWorking
        self.serial = serial
    }    
}
extension Device: Content {}
extension Device: Migration {}
extension Device: Parameter {}
```

classical method to write or read is:

```swift
import Vapor

final class DeviceController {        
    func readAll(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Device]> {
        return Device.query(on: req).all()
    }

    func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Device> {
        return try req.content.decode(Device.self).flatMap { device in
            return device.save(on: req)
        }
    }
}
```

How to replace `req` to another background, safe thread, which I can create locally?

For example:

```swift
let device = Device(isWorking: true, serial: 54321)
device.save(on: <#T##DatabaseConnectable#>)
```

How to replace `<#T##DatabaseConnectable#>` ?

I will be thankful for any help or advice.

Comment: I have the same issue. I want to "read" my database without any GET. Just get an Array with the data. No a Future<Type> returned value.

Comment: @FedeCugliandolo I have stupid workaround but it’s working and maybe it will help you. Idea is to make GET request to read from your database but make it only local host. If you need to read something from your DB, just make GET request to http://licalhost:8080 and data will come to you on new, safe thread. If you need to write, create POST local request. What do you think?

Comment: hi alex, thanks for your answer. My problem is that Im running a telegram bot, so I just have ONE POST to answer my update. Inside that POST I need to access to my DB, read a table, and send that data into my response... 
by the way, if you want to continue via telegram: @yiyinovich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question and answers ([Is is possible to use Vapor 3 Postgres Fluent in a standalone script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786970/is-is-possible-to-use-vapor-3-postgres-fluent-in-a-standalone-script)) I realized CRUD like this:

```
import Vapor
import FluentPostgreSQL

final class Device: PostgreSQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    var isWorking: Bool
    var serial: Int

    init(isWorking: Bool, serial: Int) {
        self.isWorking = isWorking
        self.serial = serial
    }
}
extension Device: Content {}
extension Device: Migration {}
extension Device: Parameter {}

final class WorkWithPostgres {

    let databaseConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", port: 5432, username: "username", database: "testestest", password: nil)

    let database: PostgreSQLDatabase

    static let shared = WorkWithPostgres()

    private init() {
        database = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: databaseConfig)
    }

    func readAll<T: PostgreSQLModel>(postgreSQLModel: T.Type, completion: (([T]) -> Void)?) {
        let worker = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)
        let conn = database.newConnection(on: worker)

        let _ = conn.map { connection in
            postgreSQLModel.query(on: connection).all().map { databaseData in
                worker.shutdownGracefully { _ in
                }

                completion?(databaseData)
            }
        }
    }

    func create<T: PostgreSQLModel>(postgreSQLModel: T) {
        let worker = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)
        let conn = database.newConnection(on: worker)

        let _ = conn.map { connection in
            let _ = postgreSQLModel.save(on: connection).whenComplete {
                worker.shutdownGracefully { _ in
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

final class DeviceController {

    func readAll(completion: (([Device]) -> Void)?) {
        WorkWithPostgres.shared.readAll(postgreSQLModel: Device.self) { devices in
            completion?(devices)
        }
    }

    func create(isWorking: Bool, serial: Int) {
        let device = Device(isWorking: isWorking, serial: serial)

        WorkWithPostgres.shared.create(postgreSQLModel: device)
    }

}
```

It is working, but I am not sure is it good way to do this. Does somebody know?

Comment: @imike Hi, sorry for disturbing you again, but what do you think about it?

Comment: Maybe, someone knows: is it reliable approach? Good one?

Answer (score 1):

`Request` is `Container`, it has `eventLoop` and it is `DatabaseConnectable`.

`Application`, it is `Container`, it has `eventLoop`, but it is not `DatabaseConnectable`.

#### How can you use `Application` for database queries?

On any `Container` you can get pooled connection to the database and this connection as you may guess is `DatabaseConnectable`.

Example query in `boot.swift`

```swift
import Vapor
import FluentSQL
import FluentPostgreSQL

public func boot(_ app: Application) throws {
    let _ = app.requestPooledConnection(to: .psql).flatMap { conn in
        return User.query(conn).all().map { users in
            print("just found \(users.count) users")
        }.always {
            try? app.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will request pooled connection to PostgreSQL via `.psql` identifier from `Application` container, then execute query on that connection, then in `always` block it release that connection back to pool.

#### Where to get a `Container` for background task?

If you use https://github.com/vapor/jobs or https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/VaporCron you will have a `Container` object in task declaration.

Example for `VaporCron`

```swift
// in boot.swift
import Vapor
import VaporCron

/// Called after your application has initialized.
public func boot(_ app: Application) throws {
    scheduleTasks(on: app)
}

/// Scheduling Cron tasks
private func scheduleTasks(on app: Application) {
    do {
        _ = try VaporCron.schedule(Every1MinCheck.self, on: app)
    } catch {
        print("cron schedule error: \(error)")
    }
}

// in Every1MinCheck.swift
import Vapor
import VaporCron
import FluentSQL
import PostgreSQL

struct Every1MinCheck: VaporCronSchedulable {
    static var expression: String { return "*/1 * * * *" } // every 1 minute

    static func task(on container: VaporCronContainer) -> Future<Void> {
        return container.requestPooledConnection(to: .psql).flatMap { conn in
            return User.query(conn).all().map { users in
                print("just found \(users.count) users")
            }.always {
                try? container.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it mostly works, except:
".always {
    app.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)
}"
But what if I want use CRUD not only in boot? Can I create background thread anywhere? Or can I extend class Device with function write?

Comment: Don't create background threads manually cause they are will be not in `eventLoop` and will not work long under high load. You could create any functions with container in parameters and do something in it. If to speak about background tasks, you could use vapor cron library and in task declaration you will have a container object. I've updated my answer, added `try?` to `always` block.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will not create manual threads. But there should be a solution to save to DB from anywhere, not only from boot, right?

Comment: You can save something to database only through `eventLoop`. If you have it anywhere then you can do it from anywhere. Check my updated answer one more time, I've added example with background task.

Comment: Ok, but, I don’t understand. It’s look like, if I need to connect to my own, local base, I cannot do it without additional libraries. And main library, who is doing this, cannot support such simple task? Can I do it by extension of Device class or by creating something with EventLoop and DatabaseConnectable?

Comment: You definitely can't do it without additional libraries, cause these additional libraries doing all encoding/decoding and transport logic for you. Server-side is about high load that's why you should use eventLoop and pass Container everywhere in the logic.

Comment: Main library provides you with `Application` and `Request` containers with `eventLoop` inside.

Comment: If you want to write simple one-file-script to run it manually you could do this and there is no need in `eventLoop` of course and there are some libs who provide database access without `eventLoop`, so you could use them.

Comment: Vapor is a huge web-server framework with its own cool logic base on swift-nio.

Comment: Wait, does FluentPostgreSQL framework support only POST and GET requests and can work only through HTTP? I cannot accept this. It's sounds like: I can build a space ship but I cannot build a simple car, because it's too hard.

Comment: FluentPostgreSQL executes queries through `DatabaseConnection`, in your case through `PostgreSQLConnection`. Where you have it you can execute your query.

Comment: Can I initialize my own connection?

Comment: Sure you can why not https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit/blob/69ccf32e9164b207f9a773edac5433fe68ae3e5b/Sources/PostgreSQL/Connection/PostgreSQLConnection.swift#L36

Comment: Do I need to install additional framework for this?

Comment: Yes to use it you should depend your app on https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit and it also depend on a bunch of other libs https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit/blob/1/Package.swift

Comment: It sounds very complex... Look, thank you for help, but I have to ask last question: Can I send Post requests, from my Vapor to my Vapor, to create new row in Database table? Because it is much easier.

Comment: Yes you can let _ = try app.make(Client.self).post("https://google.com").map { print("completed with code: \($0.http.status.code)") } (replace `app` with `req` if you need it)

Comment: No, I will use functions from DeviceController, describe them in routes and execute internal post requests to my backend from fake user, when I need to save something.