# Vapor 4 PostgreSQL CRUD without http requests

Tags: xcode, postgresql, vapor, swift5, vapor-fluent

I am writing backend using Swift 5 and Vapor 4, database is PostgreSQL 12. I have a question: how to interact with database (CRUD) locally, without POST or GET requests? All tutorials show how to CRUD only based on Request through HTTPS again. I already asked this question: [Vapor 3 PostgreSQL CRUD without requests http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755538/vapor-3-postgresql-crud-without-requests-http)
BUT IT'S NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION, Vapor 4 works completely different! Please, look at my current, working class for Vapor 3 (based on this answer: [Is is possible to use Vapor 3 Postgres Fluent in a standalone script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786970/is-is-possible-to-use-vapor-3-postgres-fluent-in-a-standalone-script)):

```swift
import Vapor
import FluentPostgreSQL

final class WorkWithPostgres {
    
    private let databaseConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", port: 5432, username: "RutrackerTech", database: "vaporpostgres", password: "ru628trac4er")
    
    let postgres: PostgreSQLDatabase
    
    static let shared = WorkWithPostgres()
    
    private init() {
        postgres = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: databaseConfig)
    }
    
    /// Will it create undeleted memory leaks?
    func shutdownGracefully(worker: MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        worker.shutdownGracefully { error in
            completion?()
        }
    }
    
    /// Will it create udeleted memory leaks?
    func connect(completion: ((MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup, PostgreSQLConnection) -> Void)?) {
        let worker = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)
        let eventLoopFuturePostgreSQLConnection = postgres.newConnection(on: worker)
        let _ = eventLoopFuturePostgreSQLConnection.map { postgreSQLConnection in
            completion?(worker, postgreSQLConnection)
        }
    }
    
    func readAll<T: PostgreSQLModel>(postgreSQLModel: T.Type, completion: (([T]) -> Void)?) {
        connect { worker, connection in
            let _ = postgreSQLModel.query(on: connection).all().map { databaseData in
                self.shutdownGracefully(worker: worker) {
                    completion?(databaseData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func create<T: PostgreSQLModel>(postgreSQLModel: T) {
        connect { worker, connection in
            let _ = postgreSQLModel.save(on: connection).whenComplete {
                self.shutdownGracefully(worker: worker, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The biggest problem: I cannot find replacement to `PostgreSQLDatabase` in `FluentPostgresDriver` or in `Fluent`.
Or, maybe, should be another approach to solve this task?

Thank you for reading, I will be thankful for any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, correct idea not to work with database like I did with Vapor 3. Now, in Vapor 4, you should use `Database` instance. Where to get it? I can suggest 2 options for you. First is `boot(_ app: Application)` in `boot.swift` or in `configure(_ app: Application)` in `configure.swift`. So `app` will have options to work with database like this: `<Model>.query(on: app.db)`. Second option is `req` in any request. `req` should be of type `Request`, like this: `<Model>.query(on: req.db)`. By `Model`, you can take any class inherited of class `Model`, for example: `final class User: Model, Content {` You should organise your code to be called from `boot.swift` or `configure.swift` or from any request, for example, in `routes.swift`

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a connection in Fluent 4 - you can just use the `database` type. So your `model.save(on:)` becomes `model.save(on: database)`

Comment: Ok, where will I take ‘database’?

Comment: What do you mean by " take database"? You already have it in that code `let postgres: PostgreSQLDatabase`

Comment: PostgreSQLDatabase - is not available anymore in Vapor 4.

Comment: You can get the database from either the `Application` or a `Request` - wherever you're using it you'll have access to one of them

Comment: Let's assume, I don't want to use Request inside (I will not send requests to my own localhost server), should I use Application all the time?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes

Comment: Ok, for example, I have some class, how can I use Application in it?

Comment: You'll need to inject it in from wherever you call that class or create it